# Copy and Paste Pixels from an Array

Tags: java, processing

Trying to fill a 10x10 Array of pixels when I click on a pixel and then paste that into a different area when i click again and keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I click anywhere on the image. Any ideas how to fix it?
This was all done in Processing

```
final int WIDTH = 1280;
final int HEIGHT = 720;
PImage pim;
int mouX;
int mouY;
color[][] pix = new color[WIDTH][HEIGHT]; 
color[][] temp = new color[10][10];

void setup() {
  size(1280,720);
  pim = loadImage("344625.jpg");
  image(pim, 0, 0);

  for(int r = 0; r < WIDTH; r++) {
    for(int c = 0; c < HEIGHT; c++) {
      pix[r][c] = pim.get(r,c);
    }
  }
}

int p = 0;
void draw() {
  mouX = mouseX;
  mouY = mouseY;
  pasty();
}

void pasty() {
  noStroke();
  if(mousePressed == true && p == 0) {
    for(int i = mouX; i < mouX + temp.length; i++) {
      for(int e = mouY; e < mouY + temp[i].length; e++) {
        temp[i][e] = pix[i][e];
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Copy");
    p = 1;
  }
  else if(mousePressed == true && p == 1) {
    System.out.println("Paste");
    for(int i = mouX; i < mouX + temp.length; i++) {
      for(int e = mouY; e < mouY + temp[i].length; e++) {
        fill(temp[i][e]);
        rect(i,e,1,1);
      }
    }
    p = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are accessing to `temp` using `i` and `e` as indexes. Those indexes use `mouX` and `mouY`, which are certainly out of your 0-9 range.

Comment: How would I then implement that then in order for it to fill the array with the correct color?

Comment: You need to [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). Which line of code has the error? What are the values of every variable on that line? What are the lengths of the arrays you're using? What indexes are you trying to access?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access temp[mouX][mouY] essentially, which will cause an exception when either your x or y coordinates go above 10. You want i and e to start at 0, so

```
temp[i-mouX][e-mouY] = pix[i][e];
```

Comment: I just tried changing it to that and I still get the ArrayIndex error

Comment: you have to use on all the places dude - fill(temp[i][e])?? thats another junk

Comment: It gives the error before even that. It does it before it even fills the array

Comment: You need to do the same thing everywhere you try to access temp[][].